# Change setter 1 / value(currency)

Tags: java, setter, multiplication

How can I change my setter so it sets:  1 / currency. Instead of just currency. Lets say the currency is 0.1074 I want to be 1/0.1074 = aprox 9,3109

```
private StringProperty currency = new SimpleStringProperty();

public CurrencyBean(String Currency) {
    setCurrency(Currency);
}

public final StringProperty currencyProperty(){
    return this.currency;
}
//GETTER
public final String getCurrency(){
    return this.currencyProperty().get();
}
//SETTER
public final void setCurrency(final String Currency){
    this.currencyProperty().set(Currency);
```

Comment: Your setter doesn't return anything, nor should it, so what exactly are you talking about?

Comment: @Stultuske Oh I mean I wanna set the value to 1/currency. Edited now my bad

Comment: Why do you use `String`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your setter doesn't return anything. It sets a field. For what you are describing you need to parse the number from the `Currency` and print it back after performing calculations. E.g.

```
double normalCurrency = Double.parseDouble(Currency);
double reciprocalCurrency = 1/normalCurrency;
String result = Double.toString(reciprocalCurrency);
```

then set this `result` anywhere you want

Comment: So It would look like this? this.currencyProperty().set(result) in my setter method?

Comment: @Dolle I don't know what `StringProperty` is, but it seems right.

Comment: what is `StringProperty` ? Maybe you have to use `this.currencyProperty().setValue(result);`

Comment: StringProperty is for javafx setValue didnt work either. My e.messsage says "For input string"

Comment: is `Currency` just the number e.g.`"0.1074"` ? are there other letters afterwards in the string ?

Comment: I get like 5 difference currencies from a csv file this is just an example.

Comment: And no there is no other letters

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem... The problem is that my reader reads all lines. And the first row in my csv file is only Strings.. thats why I get errors. When I tried Manos Nikolaidis solution.

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("currency.csv"), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

So If someone could tell me how to skip the first row I would be really happy. Because I only know how to skip the first line with a bufferedReader.